# how to export a alembic file via script in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, export, alembic

Is there any way that we can export a alembic file via script, the purpose that I want is store my own data(normals, uv, color ...) to alembic file instead of alembic itself to compute?

Answer (score -1):

I have never worked with these files and I don't know them in depth, but to find an answer I think you should try to study how they are done internally.
By studying its structure, you will be able to generate one automatically from a script.
Sorry if I can't be more helpful.
However, if you think my answer helped you, you can mark it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). I would very much appreciate it :)